Conformal map between a domain minus an arc and the unit circle
I was trying to understand the paper computability of Brolin-Lyubich measure and, in the last counter-example of the paper (page 25), they say about a conformal map between the set $(\mathbb{C}\setminus [2^{-n} - 2^{-2n}, 2^{-n} + 2^{-2n}], 0)$ and $(\mathbb{D}, 0)$, where $[a, b]$ is the shortest arc of the unit circle between $e^{2\pi ia}$ and $e^{2\pi ib}$. So, how can we construct this conformal map?  I tried to do a rotation so we can consider the arc of the form $[a, 0]$ and then I tried to use the maps of this post but didn't work, and later of this post to construct this map, and other posts too, but nothing works.
Is there any common method to do this kind of conformal map? Like a domain minus an arc to the unit disc.
So, here is my "attempt":
First, rotate the arc so we can consider the arc of the form "$[a, 0]$", then use a Mobius transformation that sends this arc to the arc $[-1, 1]$ and preserves the $0$ ($0 \mapsto 0$). Rotates and contract by $\frac{i}{2}$, then translates by $\frac{i}{2}$. To complete, use the ideia here and use a Mobius transformation in order to preserve $0$.
This ideia appear to work, i don't know (it's really right?), but is kind complicated. I didn't decide to map our initial arc to $[-1, 1]$ because it's easier to control the point $0$ in that way.
Is there any easier way to do this?
